# I am trying to locate a download link for Citus v11.3 for Postgres13. Please advise. Thanks

Tags: download, citus

Is Citus v11.3 ( single node Postgres 13 ) available for download?. If so can you please advise or provide a link to a download platform. Thanks

Have tried https://www.citusdata.com/download/
Seems to offer only Citus v12 for Postgres 15 ( on Fedora ).
I was expecting to find an option to download Citus v11.3 and other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not have packages for Fedora. Your best option is to either compile from source, or use docker images instead.